# How can I make the code segments of this page more readable?

Tags: html, wordpress

Sorry about the specific question - I'm writing up this page for my portfolio http://ashereinhorn.com/portfolio/2014/hex-tile-world-script-page-unfinished/

however the column is so narrow that it results in some undesirable formatting for the dark, code segments.

How can I make these section expand further to the right (and left?) so that there is less line wrapping.

I'm writing it all in HTML so a solution with just that would be perfect. I'm not against solutions where you have to expand them or they open a floating element that displays the content either.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```
pre {
  background-color: #272a2c;
  color: #8f969c;
  padding: 30px 15px; // reduces the padding for right and left
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1200px;
}

.single-project .entry-content {
    position: relative;
}
```

You cannot break out of your website container unless you actually close it. This is a hack to make it work, but it's not ideal for a multitude of reasons. Using absolute positioning is usually not recommended.

In your case, you would have to close the "wrapper modular clearfix" div, and start another div that has a larger width.

```
<div class="wrapper modular clearfix">
    //Article text
</div>
<div class="wrapper code-example">
    //Code insert
</div>
```

Comment: sorry to be totally ignorant, but how do I actually use this? where do I put this on my page? thanks!

Comment: wait no, I see now. yes this did help me! I'd still like to be able to break out beyond the width of the main column though, but thank you!

Comment: This isn't something you can actually do. I have a provided a "hack" for this to work though.